# Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

What's wrong with the following code?
Hapenned to me when I tried to assign an expression to an element,

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="{{MY_PREC}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    {{MY_PREC}}
  </div>
```

also tried as

```
[aria-valuenow]={{MY_PREC}}
```

Seem like it happens since RC5

any ideas?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Angular2 binding is property binding by default. There is no `aria-valuenow` property on `div` if there is no directive or component applied that has such an `@Input()`

Use instead explicit attribute binding

```
attr.aria-valuenow="{{MY_PREC}}"
```

or

```
[attr.aria-valuenow]="MY_PREC"
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I need to do something like this: `style="width:{{current_data/current_max_data | percent:'1.0-1'}}"`

Comment: [ngStyle]="{width:current_data/current_max_data | percent:'1.0-1'}"

Comment: for me worked ` [style.width]="current_data/current_max_data | percent:'1.0-1'"`

Comment: Your post saved the day for me. I am using bootstrap 4 accordion with `<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">`. I need to put my Id in aria-controls on a tag and in div aria-labelledby. For a `[attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+psl.Id"` and for div `[attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+psl.Id"` worked for me.

Comment: Sorry this answer is not very clear to me, do we need an `@Input` call or not?

Comment: @MrCholo so you think downvoting motivates me to provide free support?

Comment: I got a downvote the exact same time you posted your comment. `@Input()` is not related to this question in any way.

Answer (score 4):

In .ts file:

```
public MY_PREC = '55';
```

In .html file:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
     [attr.aria-valuenow]="MY_PREC" [style.width]="MY_PREC+'%'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
     {{MY_PREC}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you implement the new ngModule stuff ?

If so, the order of declarations has an impact on how the application should work. Maybe you should try to declare your directives in another order

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just adding
`*ngIf="MY_PREC"` solve the issue.

```js
<div *ngIf="MY_PREC" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="{{MY_PREC}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    {{MY_PREC}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

ng-style="{width: MY_PREC+ '%'}" you can dynamically change the progress inside progress bar inside progress bar tag

Comment: This dos not answer the question that OP asks