# Angular 2: Conditionally enable contenteditable

Tags: angular, data-binding, contenteditable

I have the following HTML

```html
<div class="wall-title" contenteditable="true">
        {{wall.title}}
    </div>
```

I want to be able to set the value of contenteditable based on a certain value in the model, like so

```html
<div class="wall-title" [contenteditable]="wall.title === 'Some Title'" >
        {{wall.title}}
    </div>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried `[attr.contenteditable]`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks very much.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should post this as an answer, it works like a charm!

Comment: @zolastro the question is closed, new answers can't be added. I proposed a duplicate, which the OP accepted, where the answer had already been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161129/3001761.