# Dynamically set class or id using index of ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, ngfor

So I am trying to create a collapse (accordion) in Bootstrap 4 using Angular. I would love to be able to create almost the entire thing using an ngFor loop.

So far I have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let environment of environments; let i = index;">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingi">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsei" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsei">
              Number: {{i}}
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div *ngFor="let name of uniqueNames; let j = index" class="card infoBox">
              <p>this is accordion {{i}}, section: {{j}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is use "let i = index" to set the id and class names needed to make the accordion know what to do when certain links are clicked. So ideally the first accordion section would have class and id of collapse0/heading0 and the next would have id and class of collapse1/heading1 etc.

However, the previous code must not be working because all the accordions and their headers show up and do nothing when clicked on. It does generate the correct number, show all the right headers, and the bodies associated with them.

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way also

```
id="collapse{{i}}" class="heading{{i}}" attr.aria-controls="heading{{i}}"
```

and the fact that `aria-` attributes are being handled another way in angular you have to prefix them with `attr.`. In your example should that be `attr.aria-controls="heading{{i}}"`.

Comment: when i try this way i get "Can't bind to 'aria-controls' since it isn't a known property of 'a'" in the console

Comment: an attribute like aria-controls is defined with prefixing it with `attr.`. in your case you can use `attr.aria-controls="heading{{i}}"`like mentioned in [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161129/9218391)

Comment: that did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: This issue stumped for longer than I care to admit, thanks! You are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to databind `id`:

```
<div class="card-header" role="tab" [id]="'heading'+i">
<!-- and -->
<div [id]="'collapse' + i" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" [aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i">
```

And then you can access your index via `i`.

Comment: tried to do this and it says that: Can't bind to 'aria-controls' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Answer (score 0):

*****Here is working code with bootstrap 5 accordion with *ngFor Angular 12 (dynamic id):*****

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                Installed Offer Version Details
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let lineItem of allLineItems">
                    <!-- <line-item-detail [lineItem]="lineItem"></line-item-detail>-->
                        <div class="accordion-item my-4">
                            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{{lineItem.id}}">
                                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" attr.data-bs-target="#collapse{{lineItem.id}}" aria-expanded="true" attr.aria-controls="collapse{{lineItem.id}}">
                                    {{lineItem.productType}} : {{lineItem?.productOffering?.name}}
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                            <div id="collapse{{lineItem.id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" attr.aria-labelledby="heading{{lineItem.id}}">
                                <div class="accordion-body">
                                    your body text
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </ng-container>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Even you can create sub-component of what is in ngFor like I commented the `<line-item-detail></line-item-detail>` tag.