# Angular template parse error, cant bind property

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

While trying to get components figured out when starting out on angular I was trying to make a bootstrap slider component. I wanted to be able to create a slider that I could bind my data to (and check so it doesn't exceed the max value before setting). But trying to do the code below I have run into an issue where it is telling me that the values provided cant be mapped

HTML

`<app-percentagebar [valueNow]=25 [valueMin]=0 [valueMax]=100></app-percentagebar>`

Component.html

```
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" 
    [aria-valuenow]="[valueNow]" [aria-valuemin]="[valueMin]" [aria-valuemax]="[valueMax]"></div>
  </div>
```

Component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-percentagebar',
  templateUrl: './percentagebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./percentagebar.component.scss']
})
export class PercentagebarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() valueMin: number;
  @Input() valueMax: number;
  @Input() valueNow: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" 
    [ERROR ->][aria-valuenow]="[valueNow]" [aria-valuemin]="[valueMin]" [aria-valuemax]="[valueMax]"></div>
  </div"): ng:///AppModule/PercentagebarComponent.html@2:4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161088/cant-bind-to-aria-valuenow-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post. However, as it was 3 years old and I am working a different version of Angular I assumed it might be something different.

Comment: Could be, but have you tried it?

Comment: I was dense, I did not. Though I do wonder what the 'attr' refers to. if I put that there it works.

Comment: It's a verbose way of putting attributes on DOM elements. With _some_, you can just go with the [], like: `[disabled]="someCondition"`, but `[attr.attributeName]=` should work in general case.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time I get this issue. I think it has to do with being a direct property of the component, or it being wrapped in a div. But don't quote me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" 
    [aria-valuenow]="[valueNow]" [aria-valuemin]="[valueMin]" [aria-valuemax]="[valueMax]"></div>
  </div>
```

As you can see in the [Angular docs for Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview), to bind the data you only need to put the brackets on the property and you are surrounding both the property and the value. So your code will end like this:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" 
    [attr.aria-valuenow]="valueNow" [attr.aria-valuemin]="valueMin" [attr.aria-valuemax]="valueMax"></div>
  </div>
```