# Difference between give dynamic id method in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

My question is what is the difference between this three methods:

- `[id]="item.id"`
- `[attr.id]="item.id`
- `id={{item.id}}`

Which method is the best?

Comment: I think best practice is to use the first one, but all three of them will give you the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [id]="item.id" and id="{{item.id}}" will output the same result since both are ways to bind a variable to the template. [] is using [binding sintax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) and {{}} [iterpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation). Both uses are OK as far as i know and it is up to your preference.

On the other hand [attr.id]="id" might get you a different result. This will put the value of the variable id to the attribute ID of the html.
e.g: if variable id=1234.

```
<div [attr.id]="id"></div> => <div id="1234"></div>
```

But if you have a component with an input named "id" such as:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `<h1>Hello your ID is: {{id}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

Using [attr.id] is not the same as using [id].

- [id] will populate the input variable of the component named "id"
- [attr.id] will define the HTML attribute "id"

Hope this helps solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the difference between attributes and properties

The first is [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property), which is commonly used in binding to dynamic **HTML properties**. Its correct use case is that first example `[id]="item.id"`, in which the HTML property is ID

The third is [text interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation), commonly used to "incorporate dynamic **string values** into your HTML templates". The correct use case should be `<p>Audi has sold {{totalCarsSold}} cars in 2021</p>`, where `totalCarsSold` is defined in your component. Even though the third works as well, it is not recommended in binding HTML properties.

The second one, however, is [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-an-attribute). Since angular uses property bindings, it cannot 'understand' the role of that attribute that has been bound as a property. The prefix `.attr` must therefore be used to tell angular that that is an attribute being used. For example, in a case of a dynamic progress bar below,

`<div style="width: {{progress}}%" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress"> {{progress}}% </div>`
since aria is an attribute, it must be prefixed with the `.attr`, or else angular throws an error `Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Be sure to check the above links for detailed use cases, or this [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161129/17031180) on the same